# Autocomplete text view with customize suggestion view in android?

Tags: android

I want to show autocomplete Textview suggestion **on top of the  android default keyboard** in horizontal scroll bar instead default drop down list to autocomplete  Textview..
(i have tried using custom view but it doesn't work as per my requirement)

Thanks in Adv!!